# I am not able to align the heading of my Web Page using some code editors but it works for other code editors, is something wrong in my code?

Tags: html, css, attributes

This is sample code(HTML):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="The_secondweb.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title><!-- There will be a title --></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="title">Welcome to this website</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is what I did in CSS:

```
#title{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Problem:

When I don't use the id attribute the text don't gets aligned to the center, but when I don't use the id attribute the code does what it should. Am I doing something wrong while using the id attribute or we cannot align the text to center using any attribute we should name the tag in CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using class you have to use "." whereas "#" is used in case of id.

You can also do it with inline styling in html as below:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="The_secondweb.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title><!-- There will be a title --></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 style="text-align: center;">Welcome to this website</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank You for your kind help, I was  able to align my heading to the center but at the same time it got me wondering that why is my code not working, is it something that we cannot align our tags using attributes?

Answer (score 0):

using # in CSS is id selector

```
.title{
    text-align: center;
}
```

when your use classes

Comment: Dude, I had done the same thing but it didn't work